# How to add Dynamic URL part that contains a slash

Tags: python, django, url

I'm using a dynamic part in the `URL` in my Django project, as `<str:item_code>`, some times the str contains a slash `/` which causes an error not found.

here is how my URL pattern looks like :

```py
    path('find/the/item/<str:item_description>/', views.find_the_item, name="find_the_item"),
```

is there anyway to force the url to ignore all slashes inside this `<str:item_description>` part ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Django, but reading the docs it looks as if you might be able to use the `path` specified instead of `str`:

```
path('find/the/item/<path:item_description>/', views.find_the_item, name="find_the_item"),
```

The `path` specifier "Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than just a segment of a URL path as with str.".

(from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters)